# Bash: list different prefixes of files

Tags: regex, bash

Suppose we have series of files, listed as:

```
T001_000.txt
T001_001.txt
T001_002.txt
T005_000.txt
T005_001.txt
T012_000.txt
...
T100_000.txt
```

We want to merge files with same T??? prefix. For example, every file with prefix T001 we want to do:

```
merge T001_*.txt > newT001.txt #i just made up this function
```

How to get from bash list of different prefixes?

Comment: Your `merge T001_*.txt > ...` example suggests that you want the files ordered by name?  That is what the shell pattern would do.  Can there be duplicate entries?  Are entries supposed to be ordered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pure BASH way of getting the prefixes:

```
for file in *.txt
do
     echo "${file%_*.txt}"
done | sort -u
```

This will give you a list of all the file prefixes. From there, you could use this to do your cat.

The `for` loop goes through all of your files. You could say `for file in T*_*.txt` to limit what files you're picking up.

The `${file%_*.txt}` is a small right pattern filter which removes the `_*.txt` from the variable `$file`. The `sort -u` sorts all of these prefixes, and combines duplicates.

The best way is to use this as a function:

```
function prefix
{
    for file in *.txt
    do
        echo "${file%_.txt}"
    done | sort -u
}

prefix | while read prefix
do
   ${prefix}_*.txt > cat $prefix.txt
done
```

Note the `${...}` around the name. That's because `$prefix_` is also a valid shell script variable. I need the `${prefix}` to let the shell know that I'm talking about `$prefix` and not `$prefix_`.

Comment: Clever. Simple. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

This script will extract prefixes from all source files (starting with T) and merge them into the smaller set of "newT????.txt" files.

```
for file in T*.txt; do
        out="${file%_*}"
        cat $file >> new$out.txt
done;
```

Comment: This merges *all* the `T*` files into a single file. The OP wants merged files by input file prefix.

Comment: No, this will only merge files with T*.txt. To merge only files with T001 just change the first line to: "for file in T001*.txt; do"

Comment: Yes, I said "*all* the `T*` files". And yes, the OP could manually write X loops like this but the question was specifically about how to find those prefixes.

Comment: Exactly. I know how to for i in * :P Because for now I have only 8 different prefixes for T i can do this by hand, but idea is i will have it ~1000. Good luck with manually typing.

Comment: Edited the answer. I've tested it against the example set. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just literally want to cat all the similarly prefixed files together one after the other and your prefixes are all the bits before the `_` in the filename then this should do what you want.

```
awk '
    # When we are looking at the first line in a new file.
    FNR==1{
        # Find the index of the '_' character.
        ind=index(FILENAME, "_")
        # Construct the appropriate new filename.
        name="new" substr(FILENAME, 1, ind-1) ".txt"
    }
    {
        # Print the current line to the current filename.
        print > name
    }
' T*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below creates the scenario you described and solves it:

```
#! /bin/bash

# The code below generates the scenario you described
mkdir /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test
seq 1 10 | xargs printf "%.3d\n" |\
    while read x; do 
        seq 1 10 | xargs printf "%.3d\n" |\
        while read y; do 
            echo $x $y > T${x}_${y}.txt
        done 
    done


# The code below solves you problem

# Line below will create a list with unique prefixes
ls | grep -Po '^T\d+' | sort -u  |\
    while read prefix; do 
        # then for each prefix we merge those files
        ls | grep "^${prefix}_"| xargs  cat > comb_${prefix}.txt  
    done
```

As result you should have 10 comb_{prefix}.txt files which look like:

```
tiago@dell:~$ cat /tmp/test/comb_T008.txt 
008 001
008 002
008 003
008 004
008 005
008 006
008 007
008 008
008 009
008 010
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want the prefixes, you can use bash 4 associative arrays to unique-ify very fast:

```
declare -A f
for x in *; do f[${x%%_*}]=1; done
printf 'Found %d prefixes\n' "${#f[@]}"
```

Here's a solution that minimizes the number of external calls.

```
shopt -s nullglob # Do not expand globs that match no files
for pat in T{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}; do
    files=( "$pat"_*.txt )
    if (( ${#files[@]} )); then
        cat "$pat"_*.txt > "${pat}_combined.txt"
    fi
done
```